# Is it allowed to use any type for a @published attribute in a polymer element?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a custom polymer element like this :

```dart
@CustomTag('my-game')
class GameElement extends PolymerElement {
  @published GameState state;

  // .....
}
```

And I use it like this :

```html
<my-game state="{{ state }}" />
```

As the `attributes` property on Element is a `Map<String, String>` is it allowed to use any type for *@published* attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this works.
I use this to assign my model classes from parent to child elements.

Do you have any issues with it?

An issue with this is, that the DOM doesn't see the attribute being added.
In an unit test I tried to use a MutationObserver to be notified when an attribut was set,
but this works only when a primitive value is assigned.

see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17472

Comment: No real issue, but the type of `attributes` gave me some questions and I haven't found a doc to confirm that any object can be used as attribute. For example I can't use `attributes['state'] = newState` because `newState` is not a `String`.

Comment: This way it doesn't work, you have to get access to the element and  set it like `($['myelm'] as GameElement).state = newState;` (You don't have to cast of course if you don't mind the warning.) When used as attribute it only works with `String` (don't know if int would work as well). This is the reason for my issue described above. But the declarative way (like in your question) and direct field access always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Günter for your quick answer :)

Comment: Of course, I got conditioned this way. When I'm not quick the questions are already answered by you ;-).